# Items in outliner marked as visible yet are invisible?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, outliner

[image: explanation]

I don't use Blender, just so you know. I know little about the program itself. Recently I purchased a package with various rock formations and there is one scene that I can't figure out.

When I open it I see 2 arch formations in the viewport, but when I look in the textures folder and outliner I see things that indicate that there are more items in this scene.

When I export everything in the scene as obj and import it in Maya I end up with rockformations that to me indicate that these belong to what the outliner states as cliffs, but I can't get them visible in the viewport. The eye marker is visible and I don't know what to do with these cause I can't specify what is going on.

Can anyone tell me how I can make these visible in the viewport?
At least then I can properly see them.

Comment: There are many reasons for this to happen. Could you please upload your  .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: maybe it is in the next layer press the keyboard 1 2 3 numbers on the left top side

Comment: When I press 1 2 3 nothing happens. I am managing in exporting them, the scene is very model heavy so I can do it one at a time.

I can't upload the blend file itself due to licensing.

Though I am managing.

Comment: @WaffleToaster you can take a copy of your "licensed" file and simpilify it to only include one or two of the objects where the issue is happening to be able to help you.